# Postgres docker service won't start if volume doesn't exist beforehand

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm using this `swarm/compose-file`:

```
services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
    volumes:
      - /home/patres/postgres/pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pg_data:
```

When I use it to bring up a `stack`, the `db service` doesn't converge/replicate:

```
$ docker stack deploy pg --compose-file docker-compose.yml
Ignoring unsupported options: restart

Creating network pg_default2
Creating service pg_db

$ docker service ls
ID             NAME      MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE             PORTS
97v0tr0w0ghg   pg_db     replicated   0/1        postgres:latest

$ docker service logs -f pg_db
<no logs appear>
```

`docker service inspect pg_db` reveals a `bind mount`, however in `composefile` I specified a `volume`:

```
"Mounts": [
   {
      "Type": "bind",
      "Source": "/home/patres/postgres/pg_data",
      "Target": "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
   }
],
```

However if I use `docker-compose up` on the same `composefile`, the `volume` gets
created automatically and the `container` starts:

```
db_1  | 2021-12-27 20:20:54.944 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

See the `volume` getting created:

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     postgres_pg_data
```

I then stopped the container...

Now when the `volume` is created and I try to bring up the `stack` again, the `service` converges:

```
$ docker stack deploy pg --compose-file docker-compose.yml
Ignoring unsupported options: restart

Creating network pg_default
Creating service pg_db

ID             NAME      MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE             PORTS
zmjlzfu2nsjb   pg_db     replicated   1/1        postgres:latest
```

Comment: `- /home/patres/postgres/pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data` specifies a bind mount. If you want to use a volume instead the syntax is `- pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data`

Comment: Thank you, this has solved the issue.